# Expand tabs in file with utf8 characters

Tags: posix, unicode, whitespace, tabulation

I use `expand` to expand tabs to spaces. For `utf8` files `expand` doesn't work correctly. E.g. in `ć\ta` tab is expanded to 6 spaces while in `a\ta` to 7 spaces.

How do I make it work for `utf8` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a short bit of Python3 code, and just pipe the text thrugh it:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys, os
for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    sys.stdout.write(line.expandtabs())
```